# The user aborted a request in Next.js 14+

Tags: next.js14

1. I have created a new Next.js project using the following command: `npx create-next-app`
2. After creating a new Next.js project I was run the following command: `yarn dev`
   But I have checked the following issue: `The user aborted a request issue`
3. I was run this command, then normal works.
   `yarn start`
4. Next.js 13.x.x normal working without any issues.

Current information:
Machine: Ubuntu 22.04
Node.js: 18.17.1
Next.js: 14.0.4

I hope anyone help me resolve this issue. Thank you.

I want to running a new Next.js project without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with Next 14.1.0. I deleted the .next folder and ran 'npm run dev' (because I am on Windows using npm), which rebuilds the .next folder. I still got the message, but I let the server run for around 1min, just to see what would happen. The project eventually started working, so I restarted the server and I don't have the issue anymore.

The above is certainly not a diagnosis of the problem, but this is what worked for me. I noticed this 'next\dist\compiled\node-fetch\index.js' occurred a number of times in the error messages provided by Next. Looking through the error logs, it seems there is some issue with the compiler and node.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue while using my Mac. In my case, it was also giving `permission denied`.

`sudo yarn dev` or `sudo npx yarn dev` worked for me

**Solution 2:**

- install canary at  [`v14.1.1-canary.80`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v14.1.1-canary.80). `yarn add next@14.1.1-canary.80`.
- delete `.next` folder and run `yarn dev` again.